# Flag did not get answered

Tags: discussion

I have flagged [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375850/how-to-type-in-hebrew-in-ubuntu-13-10) 6 days ago as duplicate, but my flag is still active to this day. Usually it takes 2 days at max to get it accepted/declined.

Please understand I am not complaining about the moderator work, they are volunteer people with a life after all.

The thing is I am testing the [Android application of SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app). And I flagged the question from the application (and it's the only one I did). I just like an answer to know if the flag was received or not, so I know if I should report it as bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I view the question I don't see an active moderator flag on it. When I look at the flags screen for that question (which shows all historical administrative flags and votes), I see your flag as a "recommend closure" as as duplicate.

I know you don't have the privileges to lodge close votes but I think that's how duplicate flags are handled these days. I'm not certain, if somebody could link to something explaining that, I think we'd all appreciate it). So yeah, they're not the same as a standard moderator flag in a few ways:

- We aren't told about it explicitly like a moderator flag.
- The question is added to the [review queue for closures](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/) so other high-reputation users can see if the question needs action (and they can lodge their own votes). There are 300 questions in that queue. It might take more than a few days to get to your flag.

And in fairness, a duplicate question flag is not something that needs to pass through the hands of the moderators. We have enough real flags to deal with as it is.

---

While typing this question, the Community user (a bot) has marked your flag as useful and there is now a proper close vote on the question.

This is because another user lodged a proper close vote (probably because they saw this thread) and that has replaced your soft-vote.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, I think it's just the system taking a while to deal with the backlog of close votes. And this type of flag not behaving how you expected.

Comment: Relevant [Was this flag lost somehow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186955)